# SQL Server conditional crosstab

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

Using MS-SQL I am looking for the best way to construct a conditional crosstab query I guess is the best way to describe it.

Simplifying it here, I have a dataset of CLIENTS (each with a unique ID). Each of these clients is assigned to a TEAM. Most clients are assigned to only 1 team, however some can be assigned to 2, 3 or up to 5 teams. I would like my query results to look like the following:

```
Client_ID  Assigned_Team1  Assigned_Team2  Assigned_Team3  Assigned_Team4  Assigned_Team5
---------  --------------  --------------  --------------  --------------  --------------
87496      Red Team        Null            Null            Null            Null
74559      Red Team        Blue Team       White Team      Null            Null
56345      Blue Team       Green Team      Null            Null            Null
21473      Yellow Team     Blue Team       White Team      Red Team        Green Team
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the result you will want to use `row_number()`.  The row_number will be used to assign a sequential value to each team for the `client_id`.  This sequential number is then used to transform the result into columns.  There are a few ways that you can convert your rows of data into columns. (Note: I am guessing on the table structure)

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select client_id,
  max(case when seq = 1 then team end) Assigned_Team1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then team end) Assigned_Team2,
  max(case when seq = 3 then team end) Assigned_Team3,
  max(case when seq = 4 then team end) Assigned_Team4,
  max(case when seq = 5 then team end) Assigned_Team5
from 
(
  select client_id, team,
    row_number() over(partition by client_id order by team) seq
  from clients
) d
group by client_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8867d/1).

Or you can use the PIVOT function:

```
select client_id,
  [1] Assigned_Team1,
  [2] Assigned_Team2, 
  [3] Assigned_Team3, 
  [4] Assigned_Team4,
  [5] Assigned_Team5
from 
(
  select client_id, team,
    row_number() over(partition by client_id order by team) seq
  from clients
) d
pivot
(
  max(team)
  for seq in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8867d/2)